# Are all transformations completed before save part of saveAsTable action executes in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

In my application, I have done some transformations like mapPartition, filter, drop etc on my dataset and then finally executing the following action

```
inputDf.write()
       .format(Constants.FORMAT)
       .mode(Constants.MODE)
       .option("path", Constants.PATH)
       .saveAsTable(Constants.TABLENAME);
```

I understand that when saveAstable is encountered, the spark will start completing the transformation executions. So, I want to understand is the inputDf fully evaluated(all transformations finished) before the save to hive starts or it starts even when partial evaluation of the dataset has been done?

I have been searching the internet for this but am unable to find an answer. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Transformations are kind of operations which will transform your RDD
>   data from one form to another. And when you apply this operation on
>   any RDD, you will get a new RDD with transformed data (RDDs in Spark
>   are immutable). Operations like map, filter, flatMap etc. are
>   transformations.
>
> When you apply the transformation on any RDD it will not perform the
>   operation immediately. It will create a DAG(Directed Acyclic Graph)
>   using the applied operation, source RDD and function used for
>   transformation. And it will keep on building this graph using the
>   references till you apply any action operation on the last lined up
>   RDD. That is why the transformation in Spark are lazy.
>
> So in your case inputDf has gone through different transformation
>   before it call action saveAsTable in your case, during transformation
>   spark execution engine will create only DAG. Here DAG means it will
>   evaluate    execution plan for transformation. When  saveAsTable
>   action occurs it will start execution of DAG has created. So there is
>   not partial evaluation happen before saveAsTable method get called and to 
>   answer your question, yes, saving data in hive table starts at the
>   end, after transformations completed otherwise you will find messy
>   results in hive table. You can check DAG on resource manager URL to
>   confirm this.

Comment: Whoever down voted this, post right answer if above one is wrong.

Comment: I didn't downvoted it. But my question was that do all the transformations need to be finished (for the entire dataset) before the save begins? Or does spark starts the save process to hive even when partial dataset has been evaluated

Comment: @Anshul - no worries, I am not saying you did it, any ways whoever it is. To answer your question, for all transformation evaluation in spark, execution engine creats DAG which is optimised execution plan, but actual tranformation will be executed when save as table method executed. There is no partial data set evaluated, here spark evaluates is transformation execution plan using DAG.

Comment: I am asking about DAG executions only, when the actual transformations are happening. Say we have a map partition before the saveAsTable, so when the actual transformations are happening inside DAG, will all rows finish that partition and then only the hive save starts?

Comment: Yes, saving data in hive table starts at the end, after tranformations completed otherwise you will find messy results in hive table. You can check DAG on resource manager URL to confirm this.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I did some runs today to check this and I think what you are saying is right. Thanks. Can you update your answer and add your last comment to it? I will accept it then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213623/discussion-between-ajay-sk-and-anshul).